# Project a multi-class array into a binary matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, binary-matrix

I have a simple numpy array (e.g. `[1,4,2,3,1]`) and want to project it into a binary matrix, where each value in the array maps to an indicator in that column of the matrix.

For example, this array would map to a matrix like:

```
[1], => [1,0,0,0],
[4],    [0,0,0,1],
[2],    [0,1,0,0],
[3],    [0,0,1,0],
[1]     [1,0,0,0]
```

I can do this with iterating and list comprehensions, but is there an elegant numpy solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [`broadacsting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(a[:,None] == np.arange(a.max())+1).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [28]: a = np.array([1,4,2,3,1,2,1,4])

In [29]: a[:,None] == np.arange(a.max())+1 # Booelan array
Out[29]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [30]: (a[:,None] == np.arange(a.max())+1).astype(int) # Int array
Out[30]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

---

For mapping integers that are not sequential and expecting no all `False` columns, we could use `np.unique(a)` directly for comparison against the `2D` version of input array `a`, like so -

```
In [49]: a = np.array([14,12,33,71,97])

In [50]: a[:,None] == np.unique(a) # Boolean array
Out[50]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [51]: (a[:,None] == np.unique(a)).astype(int) # Int array
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: I'm not worried about the 0 indexing, but this result will always return a square matrix instead of one column per unique value. e.g. `a = np.array([1,4,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])`

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Yeah I should have used `a.max()` there to create the range array. Fixed it.

Comment: I'm using this approach, but I think I need to use `np.unique(a).size` instead, and then map those unique values to the columns. Max assumes that there are contiguous and start at 0.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Do the edits address that issue/query?

Comment: Yes the second edit is great. Thank you for the help!